# Problems with "subprocess" module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to transform an output to a variable, I read online to use the subprocess module.

I tried this:

```
#coding: utf-8
import subprocess as sp
output = sp.check_output("echo test && pwd && ls", shell=True)
print(output)
```

But the output is:

```
# python test_subprocess.py
b'test\n/data/data/com.termux/files/home\nkali-armhf\nkalinethunter\ntest_subprocess.py\ntestip.py\nwebserver\n'
```

(Note: I use termux, a terminal emulator on Android)

How do I "convert" this output in a more clear one?
Like with no `b'` or non working `\n`?
Thanks

Comment: `output.decode().split("\n")`?

Comment: Try this:  print(output.decode('utf-8').replace('\\n', '\n'))

Comment: For more information on strings in Python 3 check out https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sb.check_output` function returns a bytes object, which is similar to a string but represents raw bytes. To actually see the decoded version of the raw data, use `print(output.decode())` instead of just printing the output.

You see the current output, because the `print` function calls `str` on the bytes object, which falls back to a representation with as much information as possible. This means, that no automatic decoding will take place.

Comment: The last sentence should say decoding instead of encoding.

Comment: @fabianegli Thanks, I always confuse the two.

Comment: This confusion is a common one. A human centered view, however, helps. Bytes look like gibberish and are some sort of a code (encoded), once decoded the message looks like "normal text".

Comment: @fabianegli No, my personal problem is that English is not my first language, so I am never sure what 'en' and what 'de' means. I even do this in classic cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I use it like this as below:

```
    data = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).decode('utf-8')
    data = data.replace('\\r\\n', '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decode (translate byte to str) and replace new lines

```
print(output.decode('utf-8').replace('\\n', '\n'))
```

Result:

```
test
/data/data/com.termux/files/home
kali-armhf
kalinethunter
test_subprocess.py
testip.py
webserver
```

Comment: This question is already answered and has an answer accepted. Also, the `replace`  call is completely superfluous. The string does not include any `\\n`, only normal `\n`.

Comment: \ is an escape char so \\n means replace chars \n with a newline that print understands.

Comment: No, that is not happening. There aren't any escaped `\` in his string. All `\` are part of a newline `\`. What is displayed in the console is actually the `repr` of the bytes. Try it in the console. If you copy his output and `print(repr)` it, it will look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

`b'` is something that is in bytes, so the output you got is also in bytes, you can decode it using `decode()` function and can use `encode()` to get back into bytes.

You can change `print(output)` to `print(output.decode())`